# How to yield a string concatenated from a list without using the built-in method, join?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, recursion

What I want to do is define my own program i.e. `group(lst)`. I want to type up a list when I run the function `group(['insert', 'list', 'here'])` and be able to return `'insertlisthere'` as a string - all of this using recursion, no usage of loops and not using the built-in method `.join()`.

So here is what I have:

```
def group(lst)
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return lst[0]
```

With this, I will get `'insert'` as my result. Now, when I add to the return and make it `return lst[0]+lst[1:]`, I get an error saying `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`.

UPDATE + fix:

```
def group(lst)
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return lst[0]+group(lst[1:])
```

I needed to add `group(lst[1:])` to my `return lst[0]`

Comment: `lst = []` what do you think that does?

Comment: @njzk2 Gives me an empty list. But if I want that to be a basis to be able to append to it, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: so if you understand that, then when you test `if len(lst) == 0:`, why are you surprised with the result?

Comment: if your expected result is a list, then why do you want to add stuff to a list anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively concatenate a list of string elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371040/how-to-recursively-concatenate-a-list-of-string-elements)

Comment: You're passing in a list (`lst`) and then replacing it with an empty list before you do any calculations. Your function should take a list and return a string. If the list has 1 item, just return the item in the list. If it contains more than 1 item, return `lst[0] + group(lst[1:])`

Comment: @Basic Ahhhh I see that now. Alright let me remove that part then.

Comment: @njzk2 Not quite a duplicate as I am looking to not use any loops.

Comment: Re: your edit, note that it's not `lst[0] + lst[1:]` but `lst[0] + group(lst[1:])` - ie you're returning a string (the first element) joined to the result of converting the _rest_ of the list into a string. This is where your recursion is happening. You take one item from the list and concatenate (`+`) it to the result of processing the _rest_ of the list. By doing this repeatedly, the list will get shorter and shorter until you've got a series that effectively does... `lst[0] + lst[1] + lst[2] + ...` Each term is added by another call to `group()`

Comment: @Basic I had initially not seen to add `group` to it where I ended up having `lst[0] + lst[1:])` and that is what was giving me this error. But now it works! Thank you very much! And I see my `lst=[]` mistake now and why that happened.

Comment: @adhamncheese if you compare the code in the first answer to the duplicate question to your own code, you'll see it is the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments, you want something like this...

```
def group(lst):

    if len(lst) == 0:
        # If we've got an empty list...
        return ''
    else:
        # Otherwise, return the first string in the list, concatenated
        # with the result of processing the rest of the list.
        return lst[0] + group(lst[1:])

print group(['a', 'test', 'case'])
```

Which will print `atestcase`

Comment: try with `group([])`

Comment: @njzk2 Good catch. Fixed. It seems like there should be a more efficient way to do the check than adding another branch, but I'm obviously too tired to see it.

Comment: there is no way to avoid the check of the final case, but you can remove the `elif len(lst) == 1:` block

Comment: @njzk2 Yep, that's what I was missing.